# sqlite database file doesn't update in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iOS app that uses sqlite, the sqlite database file is preconfigured and added in xcode. Everything works great until I need to add a new table named "activities" in this sqlite file, so I added the table for the database file, replaced the database file in xcode, and now while running on either simulator or real iOS device, it keeps complaing "no such table: activities". Even if I delete the previously installed app on my device or simulator doesn't work. What is happening there? By the way, below is the code I deal with the database file everytime I instantiate my DatabaseManager:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set the documents directory path to the documentsDirectory property.
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // Keep the database filename.
        self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

        // Copy the database file into the documents directory if necessary.
        [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory {
    // Check if the database file exists in the documents directory.
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        NSLog(@"file not exists");
        // The database file does not exist in the documents directory, so copy it from the main bundle now.
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        // Check if any error occurred during copying and display it.
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"file is already there");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, it turns out other than deleting the app on simulator/device, an extra step I need is to CLEAN Xcode to rebuild the project and then everything is good...

Comment: This is a common bug in Xcode, same thing happens in core data scheme. When things doesn't work as expected, always try to clean the workspace and temporary build directory.

Answer (score 0):

Delete database file from document directory through terminal path generated in copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory method drag and drop database file in project.make sure tables are created through terminal.